# Port identification

Tags: 12.04, port-forwarding

How can i check which services are listening on which ports on a server? Is there any command line tool available for this.

Comment: Look for information about `nmap`

Answer (score 5):

On the machine itself, run:

```
sudo netstat -pnltu
```

This will show all processes listening for TCP and UDP connections.

To scan from another machine, run:

```
sudo nmap -n -PN -sT -sU -p- hostname
```